# Config Error: Unable to find the configuration

Tags: jestjs, preact

Test suite failed to run

```
Configuration error:

Could not locate module ./codeEditor.css mapped as:
C:\Users\rantonys\source\repos\Centuri\Se.Centuri.UI\src\framework\components\__mocks__\styleMock.js.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/\.(css|scss|sass)$/": "C:\Users\rantonys\source\repos\Centuri\Se.Centuri.UI\src\framework\components\__mocks__\styleMock.js"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}

  12 | import 'prismjs/components/prism-markup';
  13 |
> 14 | import './codeEditor.css'
     | ^
  15 | import './code-editor.less'
  16 |
  17 | const formatForLanguage = (value, language = '') => {

  at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
  at Object.require (src/framework/components/autoForm/parts/codeEditor/codeEditor.js:14:1)
  at Object.require (src/framework/components/autoForm/autoForm.js:8:1)
  at Object.require (src/framework/components/details/pages/information.js:12:1)
  at Object.require (src/framework/components/details/pages/information.test.js:3:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.578 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\framework\components\details\pages\information.test.js/i with tests matching "Information\scomponent".

But I actually have the configurations added in package.json and what could be the problem